# PHP 7.2, Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array. Ingresar arrays al mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

les comento, ahora que me he pasado a PHP 7.x (7.2) me genera un pequenio error al querer ingresar datos a la tabla, ejemplo, estoy con el ingreso de detalles de compras, por ende uso array para enviar varios datos a la vez.
Pues ahor PHP no me deja usarlo como antes y por eso vengo a uds que son muy buena onda y se que me pueden alcarar las cosas para salir de esta.
Vamos a ver.

Desde esta funcion ajax envio al modelo para guardar.

```
                $tipo_comprobante = $tipo_aux;
                $codproveedor = isset($_POST["codproveedor"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["codproveedor"]):"";
                $seriecomprobante = isset($_POST["seriecomprobante"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["seriecomprobante"]):"";
                $fechahora = isset($_POST["fechahora"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["fechahora"]):"";
                $impuesto = isset($_POST["impuesto"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["impuesto"]):"";
                $totalcompra = isset($_POST["totalcompra"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["totalcompra"]):"";
                $id_user = $_SESSION['coduser'];//isset($_POST["id_user"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["id_user"]):"";
                //$id_user[]

                $response = $ingresomaterias->create($codproveedor,$tipo_comprobante,$seriecomprobante,
                    $numerocomprobante,$fechahora,$impuesto,$totalcompra,$id_user,var_dump($_POST['codarticulo']),
                    var_dump($_POST['cantidad']),var_dump($_POST['preciocomp']),var_dump($_POST['preciovent']));
                // $response = $ingresomaterias->create($codproveedor,$tipo_comprobante,$seriecomprobante,
                //  $numerocomprobante,$fechahora,$impuesto,$totalcompra,$id_user,$_POST['codarticulo'],
                //  $_POST['cantidad'],$_POST['preciocomp'],$_POST['preciovent']);
                echo $response ? "<div class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable'>
                                    <i class='icon fa fa-check-circle'></i>Success! Datos registrados satisfactoriamente
                                </div>" : 
                                "<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissable'>
                                    <i class='icon fa fa-times-circle'></i>Error! No se completo todos los registros
                                </div>";
                break;
```

Como ven, estoy usando la funcion var_dump() (en el codigo comentado // esta sin la funcion pero sale el mismo error) que estuve leyendo en la documentacion de PHP pero aun asi no me funca el codigo.

Ahora bien, este es mi modelo o la parte donde recibo los parametros.

```
        public function create($codproveedor,$tipocompro,$seriecompro,$numcompro,$fechacompro,
        $impuesto,$totalcompra,$codarticulo,$cantidad,$preciocomp,$preciovent,$id_user) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ingresomaterias (CodProveedor,TipoComprobante,SerieComprobante,
        NumeroComprobante,FechaComprobante,Impuesto,TotalCompra,created_by,updated_by) 
        VALUES('$codproveedor','$tipocompro','$seriecompro','$numcompro','$fechacompro',
        '$impuesto','$totalcompra','$id_user','$id_user')";

        $id_ingresomat_new = ejecutarConsultaRetornaID($sql);
        $item = 0;
        $var_response = true;
        //$aux = print($codarticulo);
        $arr_length = is_array($codarticulo);

        while ($item < count($arr_length)) {


            $sql_detail = "INSERT INTO detalleingreso (CodIngreso,CodArticulo,
            Cantidad,PrecioCompra,PrecioVenta,created_by,updated_by) 
            VALUES('$id_ingresomat_new','$codarticulo[$item]','$cantidad[$item]','$preciocomp[$item]',
            '$preciovent[$item]',$id_user','$id_user')";

            ejecutarConsulta($sql_detail) OR $var_response = false;
            $item = $item + 1;
        }
        return $var_response;
    }
```

Ya probe solo ingresar los datos sin el array y sin va bien, pero cuando esos arrays llegan no me soporta el codigo y por ende no van bien.

Les agradezco su colaboracion con cualquier cosa o explicacion.
En el WHILE del modelo, trate de hacer que el while me hiciera un conteo pero del arreglo del primer arreglo que seria $codarticulo.
Los arreglos que llegan son: $codarticulo,$cantidad,$preciocomp,$preciovent

El resto son parametros de una sola linea es decir, no arrays.

Este es el error que me sale.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos,

Comment: Ese `ejecutaconsulta() OR $var_responde = false`  te va a dar problemas, porque siempre que se ejecute la consulta se va a asignar ese false. Por otra parte haces muchas consultas en tu bucle y eso es bastante malo. En su lugar debes componer una consulta con varios `VALUES` y luego ejecutarla. Sino te ejecutará una por cada elemento que tengas en el bucle (si fuera correcto el código, claro)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código
`$arr_length = is_array($codarticulo);` eso estaría mal, ya que eso [devuelve un boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-array.php), por lo cual cuando intentas hacer `while ($item < count($arr_length))` tira el error, ya que el metodo `count` [requiere de un array u objeto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count) y le estas pasando un `boolean`

Pienso que debería quedar así:

```php
public function create($codproveedor,$tipocompro,$seriecompro,$numcompro,$fechacompro,
        $impuesto,$totalcompra,$codarticulo,$cantidad,$preciocomp,$preciovent,$id_user) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ingresomaterias (CodProveedor,TipoComprobante,SerieComprobante,
        NumeroComprobante,FechaComprobante,Impuesto,TotalCompra,created_by,updated_by) 
        VALUES('$codproveedor','$tipocompro','$seriecompro','$numcompro','$fechacompro',
        '$impuesto','$totalcompra','$id_user','$id_user')";

        $id_ingresomat_new = ejecutarConsultaRetornaID($sql);
        $item = 0;
        $var_response = true;
        //$aux = print($codarticulo);
        $arr_length = count($codarticulo);

        while ($item < $arr_length) {


            $sql_detail = "INSERT INTO detalleingreso (CodIngreso,CodArticulo,
            Cantidad,PrecioCompra,PrecioVenta,created_by,updated_by) 
            VALUES('$id_ingresomat_new','$codarticulo[$item]','$cantidad[$item]','$preciocomp[$item]',
            '$preciovent[$item]',$id_user','$id_user')";

            ejecutarConsulta($sql_detail) OR $var_response = false;
            $item = $item + 1;
        }
        return $var_response;
    }
```

No he probado tu código, no se que es la variable es $codarticulo ni porque buscas iterar sobre ella.

Espero que te sirve y haberte ayudado.

Suerte!

Comment: Corregido, gracias